Disable "Changes that you made may not be saved." confirm dialog in PDF.JS viewer
Is there a way to disable the confirmation dialog Changes that you made may not be saved in the PDF.JS viewer?
When an annotation (i.e. text, line drawing, text highlighting) is added to an open document in the PDF.js viewer and an attempt is made to close the document, the viewer displays the confirmation dialog Changes that you made may not be saved. Can this be switched off?

